# Display text error when invalid input?

Tags: android, textview, message, invisible

I have two radio boxes that the user can choose between, and then a next button once he has made up his mind. However, if the user should try to press Next before selecting a radio button, I want a text view that was otherwise invisible to show up, prompting him for input.

I'm just trying to figure out that last step; the textView has to be there the whole time (I think), I found an option that makes it invisible, how can I override that in the java code if the user fails to put in input?

Also, on a side note, is there an easy way to animate things on the screen to shake so as to draw attention to themselves, once this error message pops up?

Answer (score 0):

You can set values for visibility of a view,for example gone,... .Check the value and states  of other views and change the visibility of textview in corresponding it.

You can hide or show views using [`setVisibility(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) in java code.

Documents in about Animation say:

> Starting with Android 3.0, the preferred way of animating views is to
>   use the android.animation package APIs. These Animator-based classes
>   change actual properties of the View object, such as alpha and
>   translationX. This behavior is contrasted to that of the pre-3.0
>   Animation-based classes, which instead animate only how the view is
>   drawn on the display. In particular, the ViewPropertyAnimator class
>   makes animating these View properties particularly easy and efficient.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the pre-3.0 animation classes to animate
>   how Views are rendered. You can attach an Animation object to a view
>   using setAnimation(Animation) or startAnimation(Animation). The
>   animation can alter the scale, rotation, translation and alpha of a
>   view over time. If the animation is attached to a view that has
>   children, the animation will affect the entire subtree rooted by that
>   node. When an animation is started, the framework will take care of
>   redrawing the appropriate views until the animation completes.

Comment: Whoops, got it, thanks! If you have any suggestions what to look into for some animations also that would be helpful